# How to remove the recently used markers selection?

Tags: inkscape, arrow

I am using a high amount of small arrows and similar objects. The problem is that seemingly every arrow I create is adding a new entry (independent if this style already exists) on top of the markers drop down menu. This is very inconvenient if I want to use a new marker style, since I have to scroll quite far done. Also it doesn't make any sense to me to have multiple entries of the same style...

Does anybody know a solution for this problem?

Using Inkscape 9.2 in CentOS.

Comment: This sounds like you are creating the same marker over and over again from the same object. Is that correct? Or where do all the new markers come from?

If you want to get rid of unused and unneeded marker definitions, do File > Clean up document. All those that are used will stay in the list.

Comment: Many thanks, that solves the problem!

If you copy as comment as answer I could mark the question as answered.

Comment: Which part of it solved the issue? Copy+pasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the same marker for all your objects, you do not have to recreate it, only select it from the list in the 'Stroke' tab of the Fill&Stroke dialog.

If you want to get rid of unused and unneeded marker definitions, do File > Clean up document. All those that are used will stay in the list.